# Difference between FastCGI and Java Servlet API

Tags: java, servlets, fastcgi

To my understanding FastCGI and java Servlet API both are specifications to develop web application, later one very specific java.

As we already had Fast CGI apis available in java, why Sun Microsystem felt the need for new specification for developing applications in Java ? Does Java Servlet API offer any advantage over Fast CGI?

Answer (score 2):

The Servlet API offers the "advantage" that the webserver can be written in Java and directly call the application. There is no need for a byte-protocol (FastCGI). The protocol is the Servlet specification.

It is really apples to oranges if you ask me. Java developers seem to prefer running Java on the whole stack, so servlets are the norm.

Concerning why Sun wanted Servlets, well, I'd say it's obvious: If your application is developed using the Servlet spec, you're bound to Java. If it's using FastCGI, you can change the actual webserver anytime. But that's not the only reason. The Servlet spec is also a lot more ambitious than the FastCGI interface. FastCGI is low-level in comparison, really.

Answer (score 1):

On low level view FastCGI still takes a process per script or program. But Servlet engine runs all servlets in the same process.